# Building code that uses EVP_* functions in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, ssl

I am trying to build some code that uses the EVP_* functions in Ubuntu, however when I build, I get the dreaded "undefined reference" errors.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

The following line is how I compile:

```
g++ -lcrypto -lssl  *.cpp  -o IOService
[...]
crypto.cpp:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `EVP_md5'
[...]
```

The cpp files include openssl/evp.h.

I have installed the libssl1.0.0-dbg package, but those libraries get installed in /usr/lib/debug/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ where my linker doesn't seem to find them. I tried softlinking and copying the .so files, to no avail (and I have the feeling this is not the way to go).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ld is a one-pass linker, meaning that you have to add libraries *after* the object files that use them: `g++ *.cpp -o IOService -lcrypto` (I think libssl is not needed if all you need is md5)